# How to clear Java 9 JShell Console?

Tags: java, java-9, jshell

I didn't find any command to clear Java-9 JShell console. I also tried to clear the JShell Console through this program, but it doesn't work either.

```
import java.io.IOException;

class CLS {
    public static void main(String... arg) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "cls").inheritIO().start().waitFor();
    }
}
```

I think we don't have that functionality available yet in the early access. Anyone got an idea?

Comment: There is open bug to address this issue: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8153762?jql=project%20%3D%20JDK%20AND%20component%20%3D%20tools%20AND%20Subcomponent%20%3D%20jshell%20ORDER%20BY%20status%20DESC

Comment: It's not a *bug*, it's a feature request. My answer gives a workaround.

Comment: You are right @MarounMaroun, Sorry for wrong wording. it is definitely a future request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I have added clear console command in JShell. You can download it from [Try artifact](https://github.com/bhagatsingh/try-artifact)

> -> /cls

- It also supports maven in JShell.

Comment: You can use emacs bindings.  So, in this case just type:

     Ctrl-L

Answer (score 16):

Use the <kbd>Control Key</kbd>+<kbd>L or l (lower case L)</kbd> to clear the JShell console.

Comment: CTRL+L is working for me in windows 11

Answer (score 7):

You can use the following command ([reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code)):

```
System.out.print("\033[H\033[2J");
```

Example:

```
-> System.out.println("Hello, JShell!")
Hello, JShell!

-> System.out.println("How are you?")
How are you?

-> System.out.print("\033[H\033[2J");
```

Now you'll have a clear console.

Comment: Sorry, It did not work for me. I got "←[H←[2J" on console. In which OS you are testing it? I am using WINDOWS.

Comment: @B.Singh I'm running Ubuntu. Will try to find a solution for Windows.

Comment: Any reasons to why `/clear` was not a useful command developed here?

Answer (score 3):

In macOS terminal, you could use the <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> shortcut to clear the JShell console.

Answer (score 2):

There is an issue about this Bug [jshell tool: Clear screen command](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8153762)

for now,
first exit jshell by

```
 /exit
```

then

```
 cls
```

if you want to reset use

```
 /reset
```

Answer (score 0):

**OPTION A:**

Create a method: `void cls() { for( int i=0; i < 50; i++ ) { System.out.println(); } }` and call it.

**OPTION B:**

To retain it for future sessions also, append the method to a startup script as follows:

1. Create and save a file with following(retain any of yours):

`/open DEFAULT
void cls() { for( int i=0; i < 50; i++ ) { System.out.println(); } }`

2. Run the script: `/set start -retain <PATH+FILE_NAME[+EXT]>`
3. Run command(save your work before using this command): `/reset`
4. Call the method.

NOTE: Call `cls()` , not just `cls`.

EDIT: Edit the number 50 as per your screen.

Answer (score 0):

Use CTRL+L to clear Jshell screen in Windows 11 OS.